# Magento 2 customers import error : "Please make sure attribute "city" is not empty. in row(s): 1"

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2.2.3

i am trying to import a `csv` file of `magento1` in `magento2` so all is going good but the only error magento gives me on the time of importing is

> Please make sure attribute "city" is not empty. in row(s): 1

this because some of customers have no city in `address_attribute` in **CSV** file.

so could anyone tell me that how may i correct this error